# Mysql pivot rows

Tags: mysql

When I run this query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.uid, 
    t1.client_name, 
    t2.period, 
    t2.fee_amount, 
    t2.fee_type 
FROM 
    "db1"."table1" t1 
    LEFT JOIN "db1"."table2" t2 ON t1.uid = t2.uid
```

My result:

[image]

I would like to achieve this result:

[image]

In summary pivot the fee_amount and prevent rows multiplying. My problem is that our visualization software then effectively shows the same client twice in a single period

Answer (score 0):

For these things, you should always add th sanitized original data

Especially for more complex queries like this it is vital.

As you can see i can't sort the column period. If it was a date column it is simple. But so i couldn't find an answer besides a FIELD, if you have a date field use that to sortt the coliumns instead of teh field

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>     uid INTEGER, 
>     client_name VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`uid`, `client_name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1001', 'test1')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2 (
>     uid INTEGER, 
>     fee_amount INTEGER, 
>     fee_type vARCHAR(10) , 
>     period vARCHAR(10) 
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table2
>   (`uid`, `fee_amount`, `fee_type`, `period`)
> VALUES
>   ('1001', '200','mesical', 'JAN-20'),
>   ('1001', '300','housing', 'JAN-20'),
>     ('1001', '200','mesical', 'FEB-20'),
>   ('1001', '300','housing', 'FEB-20');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     t1.uid, 
>     t1.client_name, 
>     t2.period, 
>     t2.fee_amount, 
>     t2.fee_type 
> FROM 
>     table1 t1 
>     LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.uid = t2.uid
> ORDER BY FIELD(period,'JAN-20','FEB-20')
> ```
>
> ```
>  uid | client_name | period | fee_amount | fee_type
> ---: | :---------- | :----- | ---------: | :-------
> 1001 | test1       | JAN-20 |        300 | housing 
> 1001 | test1       | JAN-20 |        200 | mesical 
> 1001 | test1       | FEB-20 |        300 | housing 
> 1001 | test1       | FEB-20 |        200 | mesical
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>         CONCAT(
>           'MAX(IF(fee_type = "',
>           fee_type,
>           '" ,', fee_amount,', NULL)) AS "',
>           fee_type,'"'
>         )
>   ) INTO @sql
> FROM
>   (SELECT 
>     t1.uid, 
>     t1.client_name, 
>     t2.period, 
>     t2.fee_amount, 
>     t2.fee_type 
>     FROM 
>     table1 t1 
>     LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.uid = t2.uid) sctable;
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT     t1.uid, t1.client_name, t2.period,', @sql, ' FROM  table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.uid = t2.uid GROUP BY t1.uid, t1.client_name, t2.period ORDER BY FIELD(period,"JAN-20","FEB-20")');
> #SELECT asql;
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
>  uid | client_name | period | housing | mesical
> ---: | :---------- | :----- | ------: | ------:
> 1001 | test1       | JAN-20 |     300 |     200
> 1001 | test1       | FEB-20 |     300 |     200
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c10bf2d1ea0280b1e4c798efcef93b1)*